# Offsetting datetime data for set of rows within a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to offset a set of timestamps within a table to connect the graph (see below), but I have no idea how to do this as I am new to SQL. I've found ways to this, but only for a single row, but here I need to offset everything before `2019-09-08 22:03:05` by `+ 47` mins. How is this done?

Thank you

[image]
I need to offset data before [image: Graph]

EDIT:

I would like to update the table, not just select the values.

Comment: `select case when t < '2019-09-08 22:03:05' then dateadd(mi, 47, t) else t end from table1`?

Comment: Very similar to the answer below, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) construct to check the values in the date column against your constant value and use [`DATEADD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to apply the offset if needed.

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN mydate < CAST('2019-09-08 22:03:05' AS DATETIME)
        THEN DATEADD(minute, 47, mydate) 
        ELSE mydate
    END mydate,
    myvalue
FROM mytable
```

If you want to actually update the values, then:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mydate = DATEADD(minute, 47, mydate) 
WHERE mydate < CAST('2019-09-08 22:03:05' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Okay, I will look into the `case` construct as I don't what that is - thank you.

Comment: @CrypticParadigm: my answer contains links to the documentation, for you to look into.

Comment: should it be a `<` instead of `>` in my case?

Comment: @CrypticParadigm: yes if you  want to offset everything *before* the given date constant, it should be `<`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: it did not work..? mydate is the name of the left column and myvalue the name of the right column, right?

Comment: @CrypticParadigm: yes indeed. What do you mean by *did not work*?

Comment: the table remained the same-- the time did not offset. The syntax is correct, however. I added the additional column names after `END` since there were more.

Comment: @CrypticParadigm: I updated my query to `CAST` the constant to a legitimate `DATETIME` datatype. Does that correspond to the datatype of your date column?

Comment: the data type I am using is datetime2(0)

Comment: @CrypticParadigm It sounds like you expect this `select` to change the data in the table, which it will obviously not.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. What would I have to do if I want to do this?

Comment: Could I do an `INTO mytable` right below the `CASE` block?

Comment: Thank you. I should have been clearer, lol. Thanks again, it worked!